# Docker containers Apache+MapServer and Apache+PHP+Mapscript

Tags: php, apache, docker-compose, mapserver

I try to dockerize old website which contains apache+php+mapscript+mapserver. I can find valid dockerfiles for apache+mapserver (later ms) and apache+php (php), in lastone I should add mapscript.

I can make docker-compose.yaml-file to load both containers. Website is used with php-container.

HOWTO: if php-container needs to use ms-container with mapscript, how it can find and use it?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with perl-script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Location: http://host-ip:port/cgi-bin/mapserv?$ENV{'QUERY_STRING'}\n\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you pick the `apache+php` dockerfile and extend it to implement `mapserver/mapscript`, based on the `mapserver/mapscripts` dockerfiles that you see around

Comment: Yeps, that's one way to solve it. I like to use newer version of mapserver (7.x), which my php environment (5.6) does not allow.